# Binary Tree Search for non key value

Tags: java, tree, binary-search-tree

I am currently looking for an recursive algorithm to find a non key value in my Tree.

I have my Node Class:

```
public class TreeNode {
    private Person person;
    private TreeNode left, right;

    public TreeNode(Person person) {
        this.person = person;
    }

    public boolean insert(Person person) {
        if (person.getAge() < this.person.getAge()){
            if (left != null){
                return left.insert(person);
            }else {
                left = new TreeNode(person);
            }
        }else{
            if (right != null){
                return right.insert(person);
            }else{
                right = new TreeNode(person);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public boolean countryExists(String country){
        if (!this.person.getCountry().equals(country)){
            if (right != null) {
                return right.countryExists(country);
            }
            if (left != null) {
                return left.countryExists(country);
            }
        }else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

The Key value here is the age of a person. I want to find out if there is a Person which comes from a specific country. Therefore I made the function countryExists(String country) I don't know how to implement this and I have searched everywhere and watched a lot of videos about post/pre/inorder. The ordering shouldn't  be a problem? I have an issue with returning the correct boolean I think...

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `countryExists` method you should return `false` after two `!= null` checks, because if execution came to this point it means that your node doesn't have left and right siblings (it's a leaf) and it's persons's country doesn't equal to the one you're looking for.

But I would suggest doing some refactoring, and instead of negating `this.person.getCountry().equals(country)`, just use it and return `true` at the beginning of the method.

```java
public boolean countryExists(String country) {
    if (this.person.getCountry().equals(country)) {
        return true;
    }

    if (right != null) {
        return right.countryExists(country);
    }
    if (left != null) {
        return left.countryExists(country);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Also, this is `O(n)` solution, because you're not using a key to cut off entire branches, and doing full tree traversal.

To make it `O(log n)` (in the case when the tree is balanced), you need to use `country` as key and choose only one branch when searching.

Comment: Thank you! But with this solution I'm getting stuck in the outer right subtree.